# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are group elements and $a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ Prove that $a^2=b^{-2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are group elements and $a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ Prove that $a^2=b^{-2}$

I tried to start with what I'm trying to prove and work backwards with scratch work but got stuck

$(b^{-1})^2=(a^{-1}ba)(a^{-1}ba)$ Yet working with this led me nowhere trying various substitutions I don't see a way to get $a^2$ on the right side while keeping the left side unchanged. Is this the right approach and I"m not seeing a clever substitution or is another approach better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{equation}
b^{-1} = a^{-1} b a
= (b^{-1} a b) b a
\end{equation}
so
$$e=abba$$
and thus
$$a^{-2} = b^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it. Note that

$$
a^{-1}ba = b^{-1} \implies a = b^{-1}ab^{-1}
$$

And

$$
b^{-1}ab = a^{-1} \implies a = ba^{-1}b^{-1}
$$

So we have

$$
a^2 = (b^{-1}ab^{-1})(ba^{-1}b^{-1}) = b^{-2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}$ is equivalent to $ba=ab^{-1}$ (left-multiply by $a$).

$b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ is equivalent to $ab=ba^{-1}$ (left-multiply by $b$).

Multypling the first by the second of the above, we get $baab=ab^{-1}b a^{-1}=e$. Then left and right multiply by $b$.